# Erro de Submit de App Store - Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, itunes

Quando clico em `"Submit for Review"` no iTunes Connect, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> The Newsstand app's Info.plist must contain UINewsstandApp=true. For more information, see the Information Property List Key Reference.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: vai no seu arquivo info.plist do projeto procura por UINewsstandApp se não tiver acrescenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O cadastro que você preencheu para o review obriga que seu App esteja habilitado para aparecer na banca de jornal.

Adicione a tag UINewsstandApp na raiz do seu info.plist e set como YES.

Irá ficar assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com essa solução. Muito obrigado :) !

Answer (score 0):

Dando uma pesquisado no stack, achei uma resposta para o seu erro. Só tem que deletar o Newsstand Icon.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Não funcionou para mim... Mas valeu pela ajuda, vou aguardar para ver se alguém já passou por isso...